# Heroku how to populate images carrierwave using file.open and rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, carrierwave, populate

```
  rake db:populate (works)
  heroku run rake db:populate (works to some extent)
```

I ran into a problem when I tried to populate the database on heroku. Locally the following works perfectly and my website is populated with images.

```
  namespace :db do
     desc "Fill database with sample data"
     task populate: :environment do
     .
     .
     @uploader = ImageUploader.new(@movie_project, :image)
     @uploader.store!(File.open("app/assets/images/photos/picture.jpg"))
     @movie_project.image = @uploader
```

All MovieProjects are successfully populated with data(title, genre etc). Its only the image that doesn't get created on heroku. I suspect that this have something to do with the

```
  File.open
```

Tried things like changing directory but without success, maybe I just use the wrong directory

```
  app/assets/images => public/assets/ ?
```

I use cedar stack, rails 3.2, Carrierwave and the assets are precompiled before uploaded. This is just for testing purpose to test with different layouts. 
Creating a MovieProject and assign a picture works on Heroku, but using the above methods doesn't seems to.

//

Thanks Jon

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problems tonight, and fixed it the following way:

Firstly, make sure you have something like this in your uploader or initializer:

```
config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
```

Now, use carrierwave's `cache!` method, instead of `store!`. I also call `save!` afterwards

```
 @uploader.cache!(File.open("app/assets/images/photos/picture.jpg"))
 @movie_project.image=@uploader
 @movie_project.save!
```

Hope this helps, let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Changing to cache does not work for me, it actually doesn't even work locally on my computer. My initializer: carriewave.rb

    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
    end

Comment: If i comment out the carriewave.rb initializer it works using cache locally. The pictures are still cached using the #{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads so I'm not sure what the error lies but not assigned to the movie_project.